# Azure Service Bus Read Message Queue

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

I am fairly new to Azure but struggling to devise or find a way of reading messages in my queue. I have the following:

- Cloud Service
- Storage Account
- Queues

What I am struggling with now is, I can see via the pretty graph Portal gives me messages are being received but I would like to see the contents of them and this seems impossible to do via the Portal at least.

So I started hand cracking some code to get these messages but this doesn't work either.

```
    var credentials = new StorageCredentials("account", "key");
    var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
    var queue = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    var messages = queue.GetQueueReference("orders").GetMessages(100, TimeSpan.FromHours(10), null, null);
```

What I don't get is do I need to associate my queue with the storage?

Cheers, DS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to retrieve messages from a queue. First you need to create a CloudStorageAccount, to reference a specific storage. Second you create a new CloudQueueClient, in order connect to your CloudStorageAccount. Once you have the CloudQueueClient, you could reference the queue and create it.

```
        // Your Storage credentials
        var credentials = new StorageCredentials("account", "key");


        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

        // Create a new client
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

        // Create the queue if it doesn't already exist
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();

        // Send 10 messages to the queue
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Create a message and add it to the queue.
            CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format("Hello, World {0}", i));
            queue.AddMessage(message);
        }

        // Read next 20 messages
        foreach (CloudQueueMessage message in queue.GetMessages(20, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
        {
            // Reading content from message
            Console.WriteLine(message.AsString);

            // Process all messages in less than 5 minutes, deleting each message after processing.
            queue.DeleteMessage(message);
        }
```

Comment: I already have messages on my queue shown as outgoing and successful. How can I get access to those?

Comment: There is also a great tutorial queues: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/

Comment: In the same way, just delete the for-loop and you will just receive the existing messages.

Comment: Yeah I followed that tutorial but I have created a cloud storage account and logs are being created. However, I have a console app which sends messages and I can see that these are being received but the graph only shows you the time and date.

Comment: For me the queue.GetMessages() returns no results although the queue.Exists() method returns true.

Comment: Try the following tool to access your queue: azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com 
If you could see data in your queue via this tool, you may have to increase the TimeSpan of the GetMessages() call.

Comment: Odd thing is queues are shown but they are empty but portal says different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71344/discussion-between-net-user-hh-and-dr-schizo).